# How to unit test MatDialog (Angular Material) the correct way?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am busy wit unit testing. And I have a Matdialog form Angular material.

I tried to test this two functions:

```
openEcheqSelectorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(EcheqSelectorComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: this.participant
      }
    });
  }

  openSchemaSelectorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(SchemaSendDialogComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: this.participant
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is the complete component:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openEcheqSelectorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(EcheqSelectorComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: this.participant
      }
    });
  }

  openSchemaSelectorDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(SchemaSendDialogComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: this.participant
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But if I do this in the unit test:

```
import { async, TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ParticipantModule } from '../../participant.module';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PARTICIPANT_INFO_DTO } from 'src/app/shared/stubs/participant-info-dto.stub';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { I18nStub } from 'src/app/shared/stubs/i18n-stub';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('DetailComponent', () => {

  let component: DetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DetailComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ParticipantModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MatDialog,
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
          snapshot: {
            data: {
              participant: PARTICIPANT_INFO_DTO[0]
            }
          }
        }},
        { provide: I18n, useValue: I18nStub }
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then( () => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));

  it('should create the DetailComponent', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should open the EcheqSelectorComponent in a MatDialog', () => {
    component.openEcheqSelectorDialog();
  });

  it('Should open the SchemaSelectorDialog in a MatDialog' , () => {
    component.openSchemaSelectorDialog();
  });

});
```

Then in the code coverage of jasmine karma. Everything seems been covered- it says 100%. But I don't think this is the correct way to do the unit tests.

So my question is: Is the correct?

Or what I have to improve?

Thank you

This is the template:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="heading list-heading"><span i18n>Participant</span> - {{ participant.fullName }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="body pulled-up">
  <mat-card class="card-spacing">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title i18n>Actions</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" (click)="openEcheqSelectorDialog()" i18n>Send echeq</button>
      <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" (click)="openSchemaSelectorDialog()" i18n>Send schema</button>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card class="card-spacing">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title i18n>Overviews</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" routerLink="echeq" i18n>Echeqs</button>
        <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" routerLink="schema" i18n>Schemas</button>
        <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" routerLink="qrcode" i18n>Qrcode scans</button>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Somebody any advice? Thank you

Comment: you are not testing the second and third cases. You must expect something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you some hint to work on this. You need to create a `spy` and put `expect` on it. Something like:

*make dialog service public so that you can easily put spy on it*

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }
```

**spec.ts**

```
  it('should open the EcheqSelectorComponent in a MatDialog', () => {
    spyOn(component.dialog,'open').and.callThrough();
    component.openEcheqSelectorDialog();
    expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(EcheqSelectorComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: component.participant
      }
    });
  });

  it('Should open the SchemaSelectorDialog in a MatDialog' , () => {
    spyOn(component.dialog,'open').and.callThrough();
    component.openSchemaSelectorDialog();
    expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(SchemaSendDialogComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: component.participant
      }
    });
  });
```

Let me know if this worked for you or if you are getting error.

Comment: Thank you Vivek. I added the template. Because it works with a button click. So is it necessary to also include a test that it will work with a button click? The coverage is now 100%. But what is your advice? Thank you

Comment: @savantCodeEngineer : Unit test is all about testing the integrity of `component` and not how it `interacts` with other component, that is why we try to mock external things. In this case, your component has a behavior to open `MatDialog` when the `btn` is collect. So, if this is featured is changed and your testing is not covering it, then that is not a good coverage.  So, its good to check this in unit test

Comment: Also, try to test some important HTML `DOM` element's behavior. This might not increase code coverage sometime, but the intention of the unit test is to make sure features of the components are not changed unknowingly. I have written series of articles (in the bottom of this page) for Angular as such set of articles were hard to find over internet. https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7

Comment: i am using keyvalue pipe in my component, so while testing dialog box i am getting error keyvalue pipe could not be found , i have imported keyvalue pipe in .spec file from angular/common but it doesnt work. Any idea on this?

Comment: HTML - This is a sample code i am using key to build the code logic 
<div *ngFor='let data of namesArr | keyvalue'>
   <span>{{data.key}}</span>
</div>

Comment: @Shweta: I would also like to see your `spec` file. Please post on SO and share the link with me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903027/jasmine-keyvalue-pipe-does-not-exist  ---Please go to this link.