# Jasmine - keyvalue pipe does not exist

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test dialog box if it has opened or not. I am using a table of which one column has a view link, On Click of View link the dialog opens. I am using ngFor to populate data in it with keyvalue pipe when i try to test it , it gives keyvalue pipe does not exist.

HTML -

```
    <tr *ngFor='let data of disclosureArray | keyvalue'>
                    <td class="subject">{{data?.value[1]}}</td>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of data?.value[3]">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">
                        <div class="disclosure" [matTooltip]="item?.key">
                            {{item?.key}}
                        </div>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                    <td>J45</td>
                    <td>Moderate</td>
                    <td><a href="#" (click)='openDialog($event,data?.value[4])'>View</a></td>
                </tr>
```

TS File -

```
 openDialog(event,categoryId): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: '90vh'
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Spec File -

```
import { CommonModule, KeyValuePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DialogBoxComponent } from 'src/app/shared/dialog-box/dialog-box.component';

import { RiskDecisionsComponent } from './risk-decisions.component';

describe('RiskDecisionsComponent', () => {
  let component: RiskDecisionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RiskDecisionsComponent>;
  let event;
  let categoryId;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RiskDecisionsComponent,
                      KeyValuePipe
                    ],
      imports: [ MatDialogModule,
                 HttpClientTestingModule,
                 BrowserAnimationsModule,
                 CommonModule
                ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RiskDecisionsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('dialog should open', () => {
    spyOn(component.dialog,'open').and.callThrough();
    component.openDialog(event,categoryId);
    expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DialogBoxComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: '90vh'
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly declare the `KeyValuePipe`, it is declared in the `CommonModule` already

Comment: yes i tried removing keyvaluepipe but i still get the error.

Comment: try also putting `DialogBoxComponent` into `declarations`

Comment: @Andrei such a silly mistake.Thanks alot it worked.